# Common ownership

Tags: phrase-request, legalese

My paper starts like this:

:"Suppose you jointly own some land with a partner. One day you decide to break the partnership and divide the land between you. So you tell your partner..."

This looks awkward. My question is: what is the correct way to say that two people own something in common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way you wrote it was fine. If it was me, I would change the word order slightly:

> Suppose you and a partner jointly own some land.

That seems slightly more logical to me.

Some other possibilities:

> Suppose you and a partner are co-owners of some land.
>
> Suppose you and a partner are joint owners of some land.
>
> Suppose you and a partner own half-shares in some land.

Comment: "Joint ownership" is a very common phrase. That's the normal way to say it.